# What does the EOS block id consist of and can you predict the id

Tags: blockchains, blocks, hash, block-header

What does the EOS block id consist of and can you predict the id of the blocks that will come out in the future?
After looking at the EOS block id, there were certain rules up to the first 7 digits, but I wonder why they are random after that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

please read this documentation page and the referred links and see if it helps you answer your question
https://developers.eos.io/welcome/v2.1/protocol-guides/network_peer_protocol#31-block-id